# Lock-screen not retained when exit screensaver

Tags: lock-screen, screensaver

On my 18.04, if I lock my session, when exit the screensaver, in particular conditions, my session is no longer locked and it is accessible without typing password. In terms of security, it's ugly. The lock-screen works fine, because if I lock my session, the password is required before the screensaver appears. As soon as the screensaver activates, then when exit screensaver, no more lock-screen. My display is a TV plugged in HDMI that I switch off after enabled lock-screen. Sometimes, the lock-screen is retained when exit screensaver. Could you help me to keep the lock-screen when exit the screensaver? I don't want to enable the lock-screen systematically when exit the screensaver, only if I enabled the lock-screen manually. Thank you in advance
Edit:
In my opinion, it's a critical security bug, because I can easily reproduce the problem. It seems to appears only with HDMI TV with the below conditions.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/jrh1pnln38uizi4/Ub-Mate-lock-screen-issue.mp4?dl=0

Steps to reproduce the issue :

- Enable the locks-creen
- Check it's locked
- Press Escape to blank the screen
- Switch off the TV HDMI
- Wait 10 s
- Press Ctrl to wake-up the lock-screen
- Switch on the TV
- The lock-screen is done!
- After, no way to enable the lock-screen immediatly

Edit:

```
$ apt-cache policy xscreensaver mate-screensaver gdm
xscreensaver:
  Installé : (aucun)
  Candidat : 5.36-1ubuntu1
 Table de version :
     5.36-1ubuntu1 500
        500 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
mate-screensaver:
  Installé : 1.20.0-1
  Candidat : 1.20.0-1
 Table de version :
 *** 1.20.0-1 500
        500 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
gdm:
  Installé : (aucun)
  Candidat : (aucun)
 Table de version :
$
```

Comment: It seems that you have two lock screens. Please add output of `apt-cache policy xscreensaver mate-screensaver gdm` to the question.

Comment: @N0rbert: done. One screensaver it seems.

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue on clean Ubuntu MATE 18.04 LTS installation. Please provide more details - package names, method of MATE installation, screencast and so on.

Comment: Crossposted on Mate forum: https://ubuntu-mate.community/t/lock-screen-not-retained-when-exit-screensaver/18655